# How to set delimiter while exporting html table to xls file, so that it won't ask for delimiter separately when opening file with openOffice calc?

Tags: javascript

Javascript code to generate xls file

```
// string to be obtained in xls file in different columns
var exportString = 'Source1; 240; A/V Signal drop out; 15';  
// creating anchor tag
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'data:attachment/xls,' + exportString;
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.download = 'filename.xls';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have different delimiters so you are probably not doing anything wrong open office just needs to know what should be used as delimiter.